# Баг с отображением аватара в шапке сайта

Tags: дефект, профиль-участника

Загрузил картинку, причём именно в шапке сайта (наверху) она отображается с дефектом.

[image: Картинка с дефектом]

Comment: Попробуйте другим браузером посмотреть. Может быть, в этом просто проблема с кешированием недогрузившейся картинки.

Comment: Точно нет, можете сами проверить. https://i.stack.imgur.com/nHmcv.jpg?s=48&g=1

Comment: Хм. И правда. Судя по всему, сбойнуло при автоуменьшении картинки. Наверняка баг сжимающего кода.

Comment: То же самое в размере, скажем, 64, отображается без проблем.

Comment: Жаль ещё нет тэга как на англ версии типа profile-picture.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov тег можно создать, но чем меньше вопросов, тем меньше тегов. Будет расти кол-во вопросов - с ними и теги подтянуться.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вот и ответ на [английском SO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/275987/profile-picture-is-not-showing-up-properly). Проблема с сервисом Imgur. Надо просто перезалить изображение.

Comment: И первый комментарий к вопросу там такой же :)

Comment: [Видимо](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/users?tab=reputation), Вы ещё так и не перезалили картинку.

Comment: @alexolut Да надо бы как-то, а руки не доходят. Там просто есть ещё один баг, связанный с загрузкой аватарки а его тоже надо бы оформить, поэтому пока не занялся.